# TryParsing Enums

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, enums, c++-cli

I am parsing some enum values from a text file. In order to simplify things I am using functions like the following:

*(The sample code here uses C++/CLI but answers in C# are also welcome.)*

```
bool TryParseFontStyle(String ^string, FontStyle% style){
    try {
        FontStyle ^refStyle = dynamic_cast<FontStyle^>(
            Enum::Parse(FontStyle::typeid, string));
        if(refStyle == nullptr)
            return false;
            style = *refStyle;
        return true;
    }
    catch(Exception ^e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I need to rewrite similar functions for each enum type that I am parsing. How do I use generics to write one single function to handle any enum type?

**Update:** Found a similar question here: [How to TryParse for Enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082532/how-to-tryparse-for-enum-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static bool TryParseEnum<T> (string value, out T result) where T : struct
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        result = default (T) ;
        return false ;
    }

    try
    {
        result = (T) Enum.Parse (typeof (T), value) ;
        return true  ;
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        result = default (T) ;
        return false ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Is there any way I can restrict T to be an Enum derivative?

Answer (score 0):

This method seems to work and does not use try/catch.

```
public static bool EnumTryParse<T>(string strType,out T result)
{
    string strTypeFixed = strType.Replace(' ', '_');
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), strTypeFixed))
    {
        result = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), strTypeFixed, true);
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (string value in Enum.GetNames(typeof(T)))
        {
            if (value.Equals(strTypeFixed, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                result = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
                return true;
            }
        }
        result = default(T);
        return false;
    }
}
```

[Source](http://mironabramson.com/blog/post/2008/03/Another-version-for-the-missing-method-EnumTryParse.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

In c#:

```
Enum.Parse(typeof(yourEnum),"yourValue");
```

Just surround that with a try catch and your set to go

Comment: Actually Enum.Parse(typeof(yourEnum), "yourValue");