# Best practice in checking if a string is a datetime before converting?

Tags: c#

What's the best way to do it?

This is how I'll usually do it:

```
DateTime newDate;

try
{
    newDate = DateTime.Parse(Textbox.Text);
}
catch
{
    //isn't a datetime
    return;
}

//do stuff with the date
```

But something tells me that that is a bit wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) method instead of using your own try/catch blocks.

```
string text = "10/16/2009";
DateTime result;

if (DateTime.TryParse(text, out result))
{
    // success, result holds converted value
}
else
{
    // failed
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, what is the difference?

Comment: @John: the difference is TryParse will return a boolean to indicate whether the given text was able to be converted to a date successfully, rather than throw an exception if it fails. Using Parse throws a FormatException, which is why you would need to use a try/catch with it.

Comment: As a further note, all the BCL types that provide a `Parse` method provide a `TryParse` method as well.

Comment: I realise that but am wondering what the advantage in using a tryparse is? Is it bad to purposely throw an exception (even if you are catching it)? Basically I'm just a little unsure on what makes your way better than mine as, as far as I can tell, both should be able to achieve the same outcome? Thanks. :)

Comment: Exceptions are 'slow' compared to `TryParse`. It's also semantically wrong to use `Parse` if you expect that it might reasonably fail. If you are expecting that the input could be wrong, use `TryParse`. If you expect that it should never fail under normal use, the use `Parse` and don't catch the exception.

Comment: @Matthew: almost! There's no Enum.TryParse. Related question on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082532/

Comment: Thanks Matthew and Ahmad, great answers!

Comment: @John: Another difference is performance. Throwing an exception is an expensive process (it involves unwinding the stack, among other things). TryParse (presumably) does not throw any Exceptions behind the scenes and is therefore more efficient. (I used this SO question to find out more about the expense of throwing Exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52312/what-is-the-real-overhead-of-try-catch-in-c/52390#52390.)

Comment: @Matthew: well said. @etklaus: nice, thanks for the link. BTW, Jeff Atwood has a blog post about this too: TryParse and the Exception Tax http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/000358.html

Answer (score 3):

The best pattern to use for datetime parsing would be this

```
string DateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"; //Or any other format
DateTime dateTime;
bool success = DateTime.TryParseExact(value, DateFormat, 
       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
           DateTimeStyles.None, 
                out dateTime);
```

Never use DateTime.Parse and even DateTime.TryParse

Answer (score 2):

If you know what the format of the datetime will be, you can also use [DateTime..::.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

The DateTime.TryParse can cause problems when it is used with dates such as 01/03/2009

Is it 01 Mar or 03 Jan?

I would rather recomend that you use something other than a textbox, like a date picker, or validate the textbox so that you have something like dd MMM yyyy. very seldomly would you go wrong with that.

Answer (score 1):

Little addition to previous answers:

DateTime:

```
public static DateTime Parse(string s)
{
    return DateTimeParse.Parse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.None);
}

public static bool TryParse(string s, out DateTime result)
{
    return DateTimeParse.TryParse(s, DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, DateTimeStyles.None, out result);
}
```

DateTimeParse:

```
internal static DateTime Parse(string s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles)
{
    DateTimeResult result = new DateTimeResult();
    result.Init();
    if (!TryParse(s, dtfi, styles, ref result))
    {
        throw GetDateTimeParseException(ref result);
    }
    return result.parsedDate;
}
```

TryParse is better

References:

[Reflector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Reflector)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DateTime todate;
if(!DateTime.TryParse("2009/31/01", todate))
{
//------------conversion failed-------------//
}
```