# Generic version of Enum.Parse in C#

Tags: c#, generics, enums

I have regularly wondered why C# has not yet implemeted a Generic Enum.Parse

Lets say I have

```cs
enum MyEnum
{
   Value1,
   Value2
}
```

And from an XML file/DB entry I wish to to create an Enum.

```cs
MyEnum val = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "value1", true);
```

Could it not have been implemented as something like

```cs
MyEnum cal = Enum.Parse<MyEnum>("value1");
```

This might seem like a small issue, but it seems like an overlooked one.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It is already implemented in .NET 4 ;) Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse(VS.100).aspx).

```
MyEnum cal;
if (!Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>("value1", out cal))
   throw new Exception("value1 is not valid member of enumeration MyEnum");
```

Also the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082532/how-to-tryparse-for-enum-value) contains some interesting points.

Comment: That link is to the non-generic `Enum.Parse` method.  Did you mean to link to the new `Enum.TryParse<T>` method? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.tryparse%28VS.100%29.aspx

Comment: It is interesting that they constrained it to struct, new() instead of adding a new enum constraint to the language.

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed that already, that's exactly what I meant ;)

Comment: The interesting thing is that they wouldn't even need to put a new constraint on the language - it would just be a method which couldn't actually be expressed in C#. The C# compiler can *obey* the constraints, even if you can't write them in C# :)

Comment: Too bad TryParse<T> is just as inconvenient as the non-generic Parse.

Comment: Heads up: with `Enum.TryParse<T>`, if you convert a string representation of an integer, i.e. `"2"`, it always succeeds, regardless of any of the target enum members having an int value of `2`. You'll have to subsequently call [`IsDefined`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.isdefined(v=vs.100).aspx) on the result for complete validation.

Comment: I suggest the answer is modified to make use of more recent .NET syntax:
`if (!Enum.TryParse("value1", out MyEnum cal)) throw new Exception("...");`

Answer (score 20):

And in the desired syntax of the question:

```
MyEnum cal = Toolkit.Parse<MyEnum>("value1");
```

**Note**: Since C# forbids you from adding static extensions, you have to house the function elsewhere. i use a static `Toolkit` class that contains all these useful bits:

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or
//  more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEnum">An enumeration type.</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">A string containing the name or value to convert.</param>
/// <returns>An object of type TEnum whose value is represented by value</returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">enumType or value is null.</exception>
/// <exception cref=" System.ArgumentException"> enumType is not an System.Enum. -or- 
/// value is either an empty string or only contains white space.-or- 
/// value is a name, but not one of the named constants defined for the enumeration.</exception>
/// <exception cref="System.OverflowException">value is outside the range of the underlying type of enumType.</exception>
public static TEnum Parse<TEnum>(String value) where TEnum : struct
{
   return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Although constraining to `System.Enum` isn't allowed by C#, it is allowed in .NET and C# can *use* types or methods with such constraints.  See Jon Skeet's [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library, which includes code that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Humbug, I can't even plug my own library without someone getting there first ;)

Answer (score 8):

The generic version of [Parse<TEnum>(String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.parse?view=netcore-2.0#System_Enum_Parse__1_System_String_)  was introduced in .NET Core 2.0.
So you can [just write](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUHgNwEMwACAU1IF5SBRKCAWwDoAFEgZ3IB4BZAT3pMAfAAoARADUiAGwjlM4gJQBuPKkwBOUQBJxQxqWJzyHUgEsOIUgG9yAX2Vr8ucg0MCDeG3lJ/S0iaYML7+gfLoePZ4of7+MS5AA):

```cs
using System;

var e = Enum.Parse<MyEnum>("Value1");
Console.WriteLine($"Enum values is: {e}");

enum MyEnum
{
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

Just keep in mind this is not in "old" .Net Framework (.NET 4.8 and less) or in any .NET Standard. You need to target .NET Core >= 2 (or .NET >= 5 since Microsoft [dropped](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-net-5/) "Core" naming).

There is also a generic version of [TryParse<TEnum>(String, TEnum)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8#System_Enum_TryParse__1_System_String___0__) since .NET Framework 4.0. So you can use it like that:

```cs
if (Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>("Value2", out var e2))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Enum values is: {e2}");
}
```

or create your own helper method like:

```cs
public static class EnumUtils
{
    public static TEnum Parse<TEnum>(String value) where TEnum : struct
    {
        return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value);
    }
}

...
var e3 = EnumUtils.Parse<MyEnum>("Value1");
```

and of course you can just use non-generic version until you migrate your project to newer .NET ;)

```cs
var e4 = (MyEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyEnum), "Value1");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class EnumHelper
{
    public static T? TryParse<T>(string text)
        where T: struct
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return null;
        }

        T r;

        if (Enum.TryParse<T>(text, out r))
        {
            return r;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly modified version of @ian-boyd's answer, using an extension method to avoid the need to specify a static class name in the call:

```
MyEnum cal = "value1".Parse<MyEnum>();

/// <summary>
/// Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or
//  more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TEnum">An enumeration type.</typeparam>
/// <returns>An object of type TEnum whose value is represented by value</returns>
/// <exception cref="System.ArgumentNullException">enumType or value is null.</exception>
/// <exception cref=" System.ArgumentException"> enumType is not an System.Enum. -or- 
/// value is either an empty string or only contains white space.-or- 
/// value is a name, but not one of the named constants defined for the enumeration.</exception>
/// <exception cref="System.OverflowException">value is outside the range of the underlying type of enumType.</exception>
public static TEnum Parse<TEnum>(this String value) where TEnum : struct
{
   return (TEnum)Enum.Parse(typeof(TEnum), value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While tweaking a little with some methods, trying to build something similar to the initial proposal:

```
MyEnum cal = Enum.Parse<MyEnum>("value1");
```

it seemed to me that this syntax won´t be possible in C#, since the Enum type is treated as non-nullable.

If we call the "Enum.TryParse" method passing a value not corresponding to an item of the enum,
the Enum´s default value will be returned in the "out" variable. That´s why we need to test
the "Enum.TryParse" result first, since simply calling

```
MyEnum cal;
Enum.TryParse<MyEnum>("value1", out cal);
```

and checking "cal" value will not always give a reliable result.

Comment: the generic `Parse` could simply be a wrapper around  `TryParse` and throw an `ArgumentException` if `TryParse` returns `false`.

Comment: It can simply raise exception instead of default value. The same as non-generic version of Parse.

Comment: The idea is to avoid (when possible) exception handling, which is considered an anti-pattern for flow control (ref. https://web.archive.org/web/20140430044213/http://c2.com/cgi-bin/wiki?DontUseExceptionsForFlowControl).
According to its API specification, the Enum.TryParse method "eliminates the need for exception handling when parsing the string representation of an enumeration value." (ref. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx)