# Elegantly parsing C# Enums

Tags: c#, enums

Does anyone have a more elegant solution to parsing enums?  The following just seems like a mess to me.

```
UserType userType = (UserType)Enum.Parse(typeof(UserType), iUserType.ToString());
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I often make a generic helper for it:

```
public static T ParseEnum<T>(string value) where T:struct
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value);
}
```

You can combine that with [Jon Skeet's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) [Unstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) (or any other post IL processor) to get a proper type constraint on an enum, but that is optional.

Then you can use it like this:

```
var enumValue = ParseEnum<UserType>(iUserType.ToString());
```

---

The .NET Framework 4.0 also comes with [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317.aspx) which also offers a similar syntax, and offers a way to handle if the parse fails. For example:

```
UserType userType;
if (Enum.TryParse<UserType>(iUserType.ToString(), out userType))
{
    //Yay! Parse succeeded. The userType variable has the value.
}
else
{
    //Oh noes! The parse failed!
}
```

Comment: I'm noticing that for the Enum.TryParse(), the parsing never fails, even though I want it to for values that are not within the enum. 
My example is at: https://pastebin.com/fZfT69Lk

Comment: @Colin - interesting. This is because an integer value is always convertible to an enum, eg `(TestEnum)4737373` works and compiles, too. If you want to enforce that your value is a named value, you can use GetNames to ensure it's there.

Answer (score 4):

You can create an extesion method like this

```
public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this string s)
    {
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
    }
}
```

then in code you can use it this way (MyEnum contains values A and B):

```
string s = "B";
MyEnum e = s.ToEnum<MyEnum>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Oh I came across Tyler Brinkley's [Enums.NET](https://github.com/TylerBrinkley/Enums.NET) library which does this and more!

This other StackOverflow answer [Generic version of Enum.Parse in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247095/generic-version-of-enum-parse-in-c-sharp) led to Jon Skeet's [Unconstrained Melody](https://github.com/jskeet/unconstrained-melody) library site, where directs us to Enums.NET instead. Wow.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension method based on @vcsjones version and feedback, and from @Mones example:

```
public enum TestEnum
{
    None,
    A,
    B,
};

void Main()
{
    var testValues = new List<object>();
    testValues.AddRange(Enumerable.Range(-2, 6).Select(i => (object)i));
    testValues.AddRange(new List<string>() { String.Empty, "A", "B", "C", null });

    foreach (var testValue in testValues)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Testing value {testValue ?? String.Empty}:");
        TestEnum output;
        var enumValues = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TestEnum)).ToList();
        try
        {
            if (TestEnum.TryParse(testValue.ToString(), out output))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Succeeded with TryParse on {testValue} to {output}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to TryParse on {testValue}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Test harness caught an exception: {ex.ToString()}");
        }

        var toEnumOutput = (testValue ?? String.Empty).ToString().Parse<TestEnum>();
        Console.WriteLine($"Parse<TEnum> returned {toEnumOutput}");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

}


public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static TEnum Parse<TEnum>(this string value) where TEnum : struct
    {
        TEnum output = default(TEnum);
        var enumValues = Enum.GetNames(typeof(TEnum)).ToList();

        if (Enum.TryParse<TEnum>(value, true, out output))
            if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(TEnum), value) || value.ToString().Contains(",") || enumValues.Contains(output.ToString()))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Converted '{value}' to {output}.");
                return output;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{value} is not an underlying value of the enumeration.");
            }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{value} is not a member of the enumeration.");
        }
        return default(TEnum);
    }
}
```

The test harness gives this output:

```
Testing value -2:
Succeeded with TryParse on -2 to -2
-2 is not an underlying value of the enumeration.
Parse<TEnum> returned None


Testing value -1:
Succeeded with TryParse on -1 to -1
-1 is not an underlying value of the enumeration.
Parse<TEnum> returned None


Testing value 0:
Succeeded with TryParse on 0 to None
Converted '0' to None.
Parse<TEnum> returned None


Testing value 1:
Succeeded with TryParse on 1 to A
Converted '1' to A.
Parse<TEnum> returned A


Testing value 2:
Succeeded with TryParse on 2 to B
Converted '2' to B.
Parse<TEnum> returned B


Testing value 3:
Succeeded with TryParse on 3 to 3
3 is not an underlying value of the enumeration.
Parse<TEnum> returned None


Testing value :
Failed to TryParse on 
 is not a member of the enumeration.
Parse<TEnum> returned None


Testing value A:
Succeeded with TryParse on A to A
Converted 'A' to A.
Parse<TEnum> returned A


Testing value B:
Succeeded with TryParse on B to B
Converted 'B' to B.
Parse<TEnum> returned B


Testing value C:
Failed to TryParse on C
C is not a member of the enumeration.
Parse<TEnum> returned None


Testing value :
Test harness caught an exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at UserQuery.Main() in C:\Users\Colin\AppData\Local\Temp\3\LINQPad5\_zhvrhwll\query_ludjga.cs:line 49
 is not a member of the enumeration.
Parse<TEnum> returned None
```

References:

- [.NET Programming Guide: Constraints on Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters)
- [Sriram Sakthivel's mention of where TEnum: struct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20353807/645902)
- [MSDN: Enum.TryParse Method (String, Boolean, TEnum)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991317(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I see you worked hard on creating a well-researched answer with a nice set of tests. That's really great, but let me encourage you to try using some unit test framework. Any one, they are really similar these years. I'm tempted to rewrite your tests with **xUnit** (I really like that one, just link one nuget and off you go) to show you how cool/readable can it be, but .. probably you'd benefit more doing it yourself. Drop me a message if you wanted to try out and get stuck on something.

Comment: Hi @quetzalcoatl - appreciate the feedback. I add nUnit tests and then post a link to my test class.