# Nullable generic field in generic class

Tags: c#, class, generics, nullable

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
public class MySuperCoolClass<T>
{
    public T? myMaybeNullField {get; set;}
}
```

Is this possible?

This gives me the error:

> error CS0453: The type `T' must be a non-nullable value type in order
>   to use it as type parameter`T' in the generic type or method
>   System.Nullable'.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `where T : struct` generic constraint to get rid of the error since `Nullable<T>` accepts only `struct`.

```
public class MySuperCoolClass<T> where T : struct
{
    public T? myMaybeNullField { get; set; }
}
```

`Nullable<T>` is defined as below

```
public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
```

So you're also forced to do so, just to prevent you from doing `MySuperCoolClass<object>` which makes `object?` which is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see your job ?

```
public static Nullable<T> ToNullable<T>(this string s) where T: struct
{
    Nullable<T> result = new Nullable<T>();
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) && s.Trim().Length > 0)
        {
            TypeConverter conv = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
            result = (T)conv.ConvertFrom(s);
        }
    }
    catch { } 
    return result;
}
```