# Parsing a string to a generic Enum type

Tags: c#, json, enums

I'm trying to take some json input and parse into the correct enum type. I have 3 Enum types:

```
public class Enums
{
    public enum Motivators{
        Small_Motivator,
        Medium_Motivator,
        Large_Motivator
    }

    public enum Reactors{
        Small_Reactor,
        Large_Reactor
    }         

    public enum Movers{
        Small_Mover,
        Large_Mover
    }
}
```

I have a method that takes a generic Enum type, and parses to check which type we have.

```
    private void InitializeGenerator(Enum enumType)
    {
        if (enumType is Enums.Motivators)
        {
           // work work work work work    
        }
        else if (enumType is Enums.Reactors)
        {
          // work    
        }
        else if (enumType is Enums.Movers)
        {
          // work   
        }
        else
        {
            // we dont know what it is 
        }
    }
```

My json would look something like this..

```
{
   "WorkerType":"Small_Motivator"
}
```

And then trying to parse the json..

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken worker = jObject.GetValue("WorkerType");
Enum workerType = (Enum)Enum.Parse((typeof(Enum)), worker.ToString(), true);
InitializeGenerator(workerType);
```

throws the following error:

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Type provided must be an Enum.
```

Comment: When you parse the value of `"WorkerType"`, you already expect it to be a value from the `WorkerType` enumeration, right? So why don't you just use a `Dictionary` from attribute to corresponding enum type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easy parse string to your enum instance. But you should define enum types

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string worker = "Small_Motivator";

    var provider = new EnumProvider();

    var enumValue = provider.GetByValue(worker);
}

public class EnumProvider
{
    public object GetByValue(string sourceStr)
    {
        var enumTypes = new[]
        {
            typeof(Enums.Motivators),
            typeof(Enums.Movers),
            typeof(Enums.Reactors)
        };

        foreach (var type in enumTypes)
        {
            var enumValues = Enum.GetValues(type)
                .Cast<object>()
                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                .ToArray();

            if (enumValues.Any(x => x == sourceStr))
            {
                return Enum.Parse(type, sourceStr);
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException($"{sourceStr} not supported");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think here is where you are doing wrong:

```
Motivators workerType = (Motivators) Enum.Parse((typeof(Motivators)), worker.ToString(), true);
```

now the `worker.ToString()` must be one of "Small_Motivator" , "Medium_Motivator", "Large_Motivator".

**EDIT**

here change your Enums Class to this:

```
public class Enums
{
    public enum Motivators{
     Small_Motivator,
     Medium_Motivator,
     Large_Motivator
    }

    public enum Reactors{
     Small_Reactor,
     Large_Reactor
    }          

    public enum Movers{
     Small_Mover,
     Large_Mover
    }
    public static Enum EnumFactory(string enum_string) {
        if(enum_string.IndexOf("Motivator", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
            return (Motivators) Enum.Parse((typeof(Motivators)), enum_string, true);
        }
        else if(enum_string.IndexOf("Reactor", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
            return (Reactors) Enum.Parse((typeof(Motivators)), enum_string, true);
        }
        else if(enum_string.IndexOf("Mover", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) {
            return (Movers) Enum.Parse((typeof(Motivators)), enum_string, true);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

you can just call `Enums.EnumFactory(worker.ToString())`.

and here is a link for online runtime environment:
[link](http://rextester.com/SQDS18489)

Comment: But what happens if instead, WorkerType is a Reactor or a Mover? I need a way to deal with all enum types :)

Comment: i generally wanted to show you the correct way to Parse an Enum, but about the logic of your code that takes more time though

Comment: The fact of the matter is, there's no way for C# to know what type of `Enum` you want back. It's not going to go through all of the `Enum` types you have in your project (not to mention the CLR), trying to find a value that matches the string...

Comment: BTW, the general case of this answer's code is in .NET 4. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2247107/215552) for more info.

Comment: @TalenKylon I Think this is the best way that you can handle this

Comment: @TalenKylon I also think it's very good if you could change Enums class name to Something better linke `WorkerType`, if that's possible..

Answer (score 0):

You can't text into an `Enum`, the base class of every enums. You need to provide a more specific context like `Enums.Motivators`. But since there is 3 type of enums in your case, you can't use `Enum.Parse` unless the context is also stored in the json.

However, you can generate a dictionary that maps the text to its respective enum value:

```
public class Enums
{
    private static readonly IReadOnlyDictionary<string, Enum> mappings = typeof(Enums).GetNestedTypes()
        .Where(x => x.IsEnum)
        .SelectMany(x => x.GetEnumValues().Cast<Enum>())
        .ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(), x => x);

    public static Enum Parse(string value)
    {
        Enum result;
        if (!mappings.TryGetValue(value, out result))
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("Value: " + value);

        return result;
    }

    // your enum types below...
}
```

Usage:

```
JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);
JToken worker = jObject.GetValue("WorkerType");
InitializeGenerator(Enums.Parse(worker.ToString()));
```

Comment: Also, `Enums` should be renamed `WorkerType` and decorated as `static`.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to just serialize and deserialize the objects containing the enums using an XmlSerializer or JsonSerializer.