# Enum.TryParse not supporting in vs2008 in c#

Tags: c#, enums, tryparse

Enum.TryParse(,,out) not supporting in vs2008 in c#? why? I am trying to use but getting error that TryParse no defined.

Comment: Shame, poor you!  It takes 2-3 lines of code to write. Stop complaining.

Comment: @leppie..! I did not know about this method so that I am just asking the question. If this is shameful for me and if you know the code what I have to write then please send me the code line. I am new in dotnet.

Comment: If you were reading about it, how did you miss the part that it is a new method in .NET 4? How do you expect MS to magically include it in previous versions?

Comment: see I am not mentioned anywhere that I am reading about method.... I wanted quick answer so that I came here please stop arguing...!and I wont expect that MS should do this.

Comment: @leppie: When using the classic view on MSDN library, it erroneously tells you that `Enum.TryParse` -- and many other new types, methods etc -- *are* available in 3.5.

Comment: @Lalit: Sorry, I saw the post where you got confused. Given you an upvote now, and downvoted the source of your issue  ;P

Comment: Thanks leppie..! :) no issues..!

Comment: @LukeH , So how can i use Enum.TryParse(,,out) in VS 3.5 any link ?

Comment: @Lalit: You *can't* use it in 3.5 - the classic view documentation is wrong. (Apologies if my original comment was misleading.)

Answer (score 6):

[`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) was introduced in .NET 4. However, you might like to use my [Unconstrained Melody](http://code.google.com/p/unconstrained-melody/) library which has something similar, and many other features.

Answer (score 2):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx), `Enum.TryParse` was not added until .NET 4. VS2008 targets up to .NET 3.5SP1, so that is why you cannot access this method.

Comment: Thanks for guidance sir. If I would want to use this functionality (not method) in 3.5 then what i have to do ?

Comment: @Lalit: Take the answer from Michael ;)

Comment: @Kent: If, like me, you use the classic view on the MSDN docs then it will erroneously tell you that `Enum.TryParse` *is* available in 3.5.

Comment: @LukeH , but how to use it then , if it supports in 3.5

Comment: @Lalit: It *doesn't* support 3.5 - the classic view documentation is wrong. (Apologies if my original comment was misleading.)

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static bool TryParse<T>(this Enum theEnum, string valueToParse, out T returnValue)
 {
    returnValue = default(T);
    int intEnumValue;
    if (Int32.TryParse(valueToParse, out intEnumValue))
    {
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), intEnumValue))
        {
           returnValue = (T)(object)intEnumValue;
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: According to another question of hes I think he wants to parse a enum name (of string) into a enum not a number.

Answer (score 1):

This question includes a number of implementation approaches: [How to TryParse for Enum value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082532/how-to-tryparse-for-enum-value)

Comment: Thanks this should useful for me!