# Very basic use of Enum.TryParse doesn't work

Tags: c#

I found a very basic code as described below and I cannot get it to work in my c# windows Forms solution. I got the errors:

- The best overloaded method match for 'System.Enum.TryParse(string, out string)' has some invalid arguments
- Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Type' to 'string'

  ```
  public enum PetType
  {
      None,
      Cat = 1,
      Dog = 2
  }

  string value = "Dog";
  PetType pet = (PetType)Enum.TryParse(typeof(PetType), value);

  if (pet == PetType.Dog)
  {
      ...
  }
  ```

I don't understand where is the problem. The errors are all on the `Enum.TryParse` line. Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: `Enum.TryParse(typeof(PetType), out value);`

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx

Comment: TryParse return an enum that say if the parse was successfull, you have to pass an PetType as an out parameter to get the result

Comment: `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Enum.TryParse(string, out string)' has some invalid arguments` says it all. You're pushing a `Type` and a `string` instead of a `string` and a `out string`. Also, the return value is `bool`, not `enum`, but you already know this by now.

Comment: @FabioMarcolini `TryParse return an enum` you mean *returns a* ***bool***, right? ;)

Comment: @Nolonar damn, and there isn't even a way to edit that, shame on me

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation, [`Enum.TryParse<TEnum>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499.aspx) is a generic method that returns a boolean property. You are using it incorrectly. It uses an `out` parameter to store the result:

```
string value = "Dog";
PetType pet;
if (Enum.TryParse<PetType>(value, out pet))
{
    if (pet == PetType.Dog)
    {
        ...
    }
}
else
{
    // Show an error message to the user telling him that the value string
    // couldn't be parsed back to the PetType enum
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that my website source for examples was not a good one.

Comment: @Bronzato You were probably using `Enum.Parse`. `TryParse` is quite a bit different from `Parse`.

Comment: err.. that `out` crap got me again

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to note is that `TryParse` returns a bool not the `Type` of your enum.

The `out` parameter must point to a variable that is the `Type` of the `enum`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you ment to use Enum.Parse:

```
 PetType pet = (PetType)Enum.Parse(typeof(PetType), value);
```

TryParse only returns true if parsing succeeded, false otherwise.