# How to TryParse for Enum value in NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, enums

I have to work with .NET 3.5 but want to use TryParse method which I know belongs to .NET 4.0.
Then I searched the web for the subject and I think I found the best solution in [Simon Mourier's answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6161718/1043198)!

So I created a class of my own like follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Globalization;

namespace MyClasses
{

    public class MyEnum
    {
    // here goes all of Simons's code
    }
}
```

then I tried to use that class in a new project like follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MyClasses;

namespace MyEnumerations
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Type in a name: ");
            string userValue = Console.ReadLine();

            MyEnumeration myValue;

            if (MyEnum.EnumTryParse(myValue,userValue, out myValue))
            {
                switch (myValue)
                {
                    case MyEnumeration.Elem1:
                        Console.WriteLine("Elem1 caught!");
                        break;
                    case MyEnumeration.Elem2:
                        Console.WriteLine("Elem2 caught");
                        break;
                    case MyEnumeration.Elem3:
                        Console.WriteLine("Elem3 caught");
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Does not compute");
                        break;
                }
            }

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    enum MyEnumeration
    {
        Elem1,
        Elem2,
        Elem3
    }

}
```

but I can't get the proper sintax for using the "EnumTryParse" method: specifically it seems I can't pass correctly the first parameter which must be "Type type".

As it comes out I'm a total newby of C# and I know for sure I must be missing something that will make me whap my head once I'll get the proper sintax.  but for now I'm stuck with it.

thank you for any possible help

Answer (score 5):

As the error message is saying, you need to pass the *type* of the enum as the first argument. You also need to change the type of `myValue` to match the `out` parameter of `EnumTryParse`, so:

```
object myValue;
if (MyEnum.EnumTryParse(typeof(MyEnumeration), userValue, out myValue))
{
    MyEnumeration actualValue = (MyEnumeration) myValue;
    ...
}
```

You might also want to consider my [Unconstrained Melody](https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnconstrainedMelody/) project, which would allow:

```
MyEnumeration myValue;
if (Enums.TryParseName(userValue, out myValue))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Or with an explicit type argument:

```
MyEnumeration myValue;
if (Enums.TryParseName<MyEnumeration>(userValue, out myValue))
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

Unconstrained Melody has a bunch of generic methods, including extension methods, which allow all this to be done without the boxing and casting which is normally involved.

Comment: but it gave me two errors: 1) the best overloaded method match for 'ChojwaClasses.MyEnum.EnumTryParse(System.Type, string, out object)' has some invalid arguments 2) Argument 3: cannot convert from 'out MyEnumerations.MyEnumeration' to 'out object'

Comment: @user3598756: Right, that's telling you that the type of `myValue` is incorrect; it needs to be of type `object` to use that method. There are alternatives - you might want to look at my Unconstrained Melody project: https://www.nuget.org/packages/UnconstrainedMelody/

Comment: thank you Jon. that I also got from Thomas. as to your Unconstrained Melody project I must say I'm quite astonished. I'm just getting started with #C & VS and neither can manage most of the terms nor can understand the architecture of it all, yet. I've saved the link in my favourites ones and will certainly have a deeper and more aware look at it later in the future.

Comment: @user3598756: You don't need to understand much of Unconstrained Melody's background to use it - I've added an example here.

Comment: thank you Jon again. I'll give it a try sooner than I was thinking!

Answer (score 1):

The last parameter of the `EnumTryParse` method is `out object`, so the argument you pass must be of type `object`, not `MyEnumeration` (because `ref` and `out` parameters are invariant). Since this is not very convenient, I suggest you make the method generic instead:

```
public static bool EnumTryParse<T>(string s, out T value)
{
    value = default(T);
    if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), s))
    {
        value = (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), s);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can then call it like this:

```
if (MyEnum.EnumTryParse(userValue, out myValue))
```

(the generic type parameter is inferred automatically from the type of `myValue`, so you don't need to specify it)

Comment: yes it works. thank you. NowI'd like to change Simon's method to reflect this pattern i.e. using "out T value" as the last parameter. since Simon's method appears to be more generic. I'll try that. if you have any suggestions, I'll consider them. Thanks again

Comment: @user3598756, what makes you think Simon's answer is more generic?

Comment: I also found something else that works (and is lengthy too!) at  http://www.kiwipiet.com/2010/01/my-contribution-to-enumtryparse-methods.html. where you can also specify (as in Simon's code)casesensitivness or not.

Comment: @user3598756, just because his code is longer doesn't make it code generic ;). I looked at his code, and I don't think there's any case his method can parse and mine can't. It's just a (much) longer way to do the same thing. I'm relying on built-in .NET methods instead of implementing the logic myself, but the result is the same.

Comment: Your method doesn't manage casesensitiveness choice. While Simon's and kiwipiet's codes take it for granted to be case insensitive. I'm trying to build on your code to manage case sensitiveness upon user's choice. to this end it seems to me that try/catch block is unaivoidable. but this seems to be a programmer's concern reading this blog topics on the argument. but can't figure out why.

Comment: @user3598756, indeed, it doesn't handle the case sensitivity. And now that I think of it, it doesn't handle Flags enums either. The Enum.Parse method can handle both these cases, but the Enum.IsDefined cannot...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51970/discussion-between-user3598756-and-thomas-levesque)

Comment: @ThomasLevesque - the main reason why I originally wrote EnumTryParse was to avoid throwing exceptions (besides flags, case insensitivity, and other small things), it's not just 'a longer way to do the same thing'...