# Cast one dynamic to the type of another in c#

Tags: c#, dynamic, casting

I'm trying to write a generic function that compares expected results from reflection (but where the expectation is provided in configuration by users rather than at design time) with the actual results for arbitrary properties.

I'm running into an issue where the expected type doesn't always reflect the returned type by default - e.g. my reflection result (in a dynamic) may be an int, where the expected result is an enum member (inheriting from int).

I'd like, therefore to do the following:

```
if ((dCurrentValue as typeof(this.CheckValue)) != this.CheckValue) { oOut = false; }
```

however, this doesn't seem to work. From fumbling around the web, I've managed to find that either System.Activator or Convert.ChangeType() may be my friends. However, so far they're not working as I'd expect - e.g.:

```
dCurrentValue = Convert.ChangeType(dCurrentValue, this.CheckValue.GetType());
```

throws an exception (for the pair that alerted me to the issue) that `Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState'` - which I know to be wrong, since:

```
(int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue == -1                                    // true
((Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState)(-1)) == Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue  // true
```

NB that whilst I could put a shim in to solve for MsoTriState (i.e. check type of this.CheckValue, and explicit cast if applicable), I'd rather do this in a way that'll work for unknown enum entries.

EDIT: Thanks to the comments below, I've added a test before my tests of the form:

```
if (((Type) this.CheckValue.GetType()).IsEnum)
{
    dCurrentValue = Enum.Parse(this.CheckValue.GetType(), dCurrentValue.ToString());
}
```

which fixes my immediate issue. My guess is this combined with `Convert.ChangeType()` (which as I've mentioned, doesn't seem to like converting Enums to Ints) will cover most situations.

Comment: I don't know if I follow, but have you tried `Enum.Parse(...)`?

Comment: I haven't actually - any way I generically test if CheckValue is an Enum in the first place? Ideally I want to avoid 1001 `try {} catch {}` statements (the example != comparison I'm doing above is one of many, but illustrates the issue nicely). Will have a stab at using this though...

Comment: You can use CheckValue.GetType().IsEnum to find out.

Comment: @tobriand Check out this answer regarding `Enum.IsDefined`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1082587/858757

Comment: `IsEnum` and `Enum.Parse` look like they work for enums (which is what I'm throwing at it). I'd still like to know how to enforce a cast in the way I mention above (in case it arises for non-enums), but for now this solves the issue at hand. Submit as an answer, and I'll accept!

Answer (score 2):

The common language runtime types (`Boolean`, `SByte`, `Byte` ...) implement [IConvertible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iconvertible(v=vs.110).aspx). `Convert` works only with types which implement this interface. Сonversion between the base types is not a problem. [Enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Enum(v=vs.110).aspx) doesn't belong to the common language runtime types, but it implements `IConvertible`. It means that you can easily convert from `Enum` to the base type using `Convert.ChangeType`, but you cannot simply do  it in backward direction – there is no *bridge* between these two types. This is the reason why you caught `Invalid cast from 'System.Int32' to 'Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState'`. `IConvertible` contains method (`GetTypeCode`) which helps to gain information about the base type of `Enum`. I wrote a bit of code in order to solve your problem.

### Solution

```
public static class Comparer
{
    public static IConvertible CastToConvertible<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value is IConvertible)
        {
            return (IConvertible)Convert.ChangeType(value, ((IConvertible)value).GetTypeCode());
        }
        // this type is not supported
        throw new ArgumentException("Unknown type: " + value.GetType());
    }

    public static bool Equals<T1, T2>(T1 first, T2 second)
    {
        try
        {
            IConvertible firstConveted = CastToConvertible(first);
            IConvertible secondConverted = CastToConvertible(second);
            // standard Equals cannot compare two different types,
            // so here the second value is
            // converted to the type of the first value
            var secondChangedType = (IConvertible)Convert.ChangeType(
                secondConverted, firstConveted.GetTypeCode());
            return firstConveted.Equals(secondChangedType);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {   
            // an exception might be caught in two cases:
            // 1. One of the values cannot be converted
            // to IConvertible interface.
            // 2. The second value cannot be converted 
            // to the type of the first value.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

### Testing code

```
[TestClass]
public class ComparerTests
{
    public enum ByteEnum : byte
    {
        One = 1, Two = 2
    }

    public enum IntEnum
    {
        One = 1, Two = 2, MegaLarge = 100500
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EqualsTest()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(Comparer.Equals(2, 2));
        Assert.IsFalse(Comparer.Equals(1,2));
        Assert.IsTrue(Comparer.Equals(1, IntEnum.One));
        Assert.IsFalse(Comparer.Equals(1, IntEnum.Two));
        Assert.IsTrue(Comparer.Equals(ByteEnum.One, IntEnum.One));
        Assert.IsFalse(Comparer.Equals(ByteEnum.One, IntEnum.Two));
        Assert.IsFalse(Comparer.Equals(ByteEnum.One, IntEnum.MegaLarge)); 
    }
}
```