# Matching vb.net string value to c# enum

Tags: vb.net, c#-to-vb.net

I am using an enum that was created in c#:

```
public enum ParamChildKey
{
    [EnumMember(Value = "SYS")]
    System,
    [EnumMember(Value = "GAT")]
    Gate,
    [EnumMember(Value = "CRT")]
    Create,
    [EnumMember(Value = "FLT")]
    Fault,
}
```

I am writing code in vb.net and have a vb.net String, say "CRT" that I am trying to match up with its enum so I can pass the enum into a function.

When I write *ParamChildKey.Create.ToValue* I get a string value of "CRT" however when I use [Enum].GetValues it returns the integer index of each enum, "2" in this case.

My question is how do I get the enum by matching a string value to it so I can pass the enum into a function? So if I have a string value of "CRT" how do I get ParamChildKey.Create from the "CRT" string value? In this example I will be passing in ParamChildKey.Create into the function below.

```
GetParameterValue(paramName As Integer, Optional paramChildKey As ParamChildKey = ParamChildKey.System)
```

Comment: enum.ToObject ?? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.toobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EnumMemberAttribute is used for serialization purposes. So it's not useful in your scenario.

IMO simplest solution would be writing a swtich-case statement.

```
switch(textValue){
    case "CRT":
       return ParamChildKey.Create;
    ...
}
```

If you have a dynamic set of enumerations which change over time, you can use System.Reflection library but this performs much worse than statically written and compiled code.

Comment: I thought I may just have to use a Select-Case statement. I was hoping there was a way around it. I am stuck on .NET 3.5 right now so TryParse isn't available to me.

Answer (score 0):

To convert an string to an enum, use the `[Enum].TryParse` method which is available in .NET 4.

```
Dim p As ParamChildKey
If [Enum].TryParse("CRT", p) Then
    Console.WriteLine(p)
    Console.WriteLine(p.ToString())
End If
```

If using .NET 3.5 or below, you can use this version https://stackoverflow.com/a/1082587/3230456