# C#: Enum.TryParse() succeeds when passing "-1" even if the enum doesn't contain that value

Tags: c#, enums

I want to print the value of an enum only if its gets parsed correctly. As stated in [`Enum.TryParse()` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=net-7.0):

> Converts the string representation of the name or numeric value of one or more enumerated constants to an equivalent enumerated object. The return value indicates whether the conversion succeeded.

> Returns
> Boolean
> `true` if the conversion succeeded; `false` otherwise.

Now, considering the example below, I would expect that the call succeeds only if I try to parse strings like `"first"` or `"1"`, which are name/values of **`TestEnum`**.

But if I try to parse the string `"-1"`, the call still succeeds and I get `-1` as value, **how's that even possible??**

Example:

```cs
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public enum TestEnum
    {
        first = 0,
        second = 1,
        third = 2
    }
    
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestEnum testEnum;
        bool res;
        
        res = Enum.TryParse("first", out testEnum);
        if (res)
            Console.WriteLine ("TEST 1 - res: " + res.ToString() + ", value: " + testEnum.ToString());
            
        res = Enum.TryParse("third", out testEnum);
        if (res)
            Console.WriteLine ("TEST 2 - res: " + res.ToString() + ", value: " + testEnum.ToString());
            
        res = Enum.TryParse("1", out testEnum);
        if (res)
            Console.WriteLine ("TEST 3 - res: " + res.ToString() + ", value: " + testEnum.ToString());
            
        
        res = Enum.TryParse("-1", out testEnum);
        if (res)
            Console.WriteLine ("TEST 4 - res: " + res.ToString() + ", value: " + testEnum.ToString());
            
        res = Enum.TryParse("fourth", out testEnum);
        if (res)
            Console.WriteLine ("TEST 5 - res: " + res.ToString() + ", value: " + testEnum.ToString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
TEST 1 - res: True, value: first
TEST 2 - res: True, value: third
TEST 3 - res: True, value: second
TEST 4 - res: True, value: -1        // <-- How??
```

Link to the code: https://onlinegdb.com/1MIOnOFl6

Comment: Yep, that's how enums work in C#, (unfortunately ? at least for you, here). Related (maybe duplicate): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1082532/how-to-tryparse-for-enum-value - keep in mind that `Enum.TryParse` cannot possibly know your specific values of enums, and that an enum variable can actually hold any integer.

Comment: `false` will be returned if you pass a name such as `sfryghudfhger` that doesn't exist in the enum.

Comment: Try using [`Enum.IsDefined()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-7.0)

Comment: @Pac0 what confused me the most was not only the fact that the check succeeds for "-1", but the fact that the string gets saved in `out testEnum`. I actually didn't notice that its type was `object?` so it makes at least some more sense now. Still I fail to imagine in which case that behaviour could be useful 

Comment: @AndersonPimentel thank you, that's the method I needed :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, an enum is an integer and can hold all values a normal integer can hold. In your case,

```
TestEnum test1 = TestEnum.first;
```

will create an integer of value 0. But it is also possible to create a variable

```
TestEnum test2 = (TestEnum)-1;
```

Because -1 is a valid integer and can be assigned to `TestEnum`. This is also the reason why you typically write code like this if you use a switch with an enum:

```
switch(test)
{
   case TestEnum.first: DoSomething(); break;
   case TestEnum.second: DoSomethingElse(); break;
   case TestEnum.third: DoSomethingDifferent(); break;
   default: throw new Exception("invalid value for test");
}
```

You need the default clause because you can not rely that your enum variable is only one of the values first, second or third.

You can also change the underlying type of your enum. For example, if you declare your enum like

```
public enum TestEnum : uint { first = 0, second = 1, third= 2}
```

The assignement above will be invalid (because -1 is not a valid value for `uint`. Also,  `res = Enum.TryParse("-1", out testEnum);` will return false in that case.

If you wonder why such a behaviour can make sense, consider enums with flags option:

```
[Flags]
public enum Options
{
None = 0,
Option1 = 1,
Option2 = 2,
Option3 = 4,
Option4 = 8
}
```

Here you can write `Options options = Options.Option1 | Options.Option2`, which has the value 3 which is not defined in the enum above.

As noted in the comments, you can use the `Enum.IsDefined` method if you want to check whether the value is really defined. You can check whether the numeric value or the string is defined in your enum.

Comment: _You need the default clause because you can not rely that your enum variable is only one of the values first, second or third._ -> Indeed, also to note that the compiler will issue a warning if one omits the `default:` case.